# How Check Url Parametr and Redirect with Nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I want to check if a parameter is present in a url in nginx and then rewrite.How can i do that?

For e.g if url is http://website.com/Cat-8/ID-1/Ads-4-3?page=1 then redirect user to http://website.com/Cat-8/ID-1/Ads-4-3

Only redirect page with **Cat-** and end with **?page=1**

E.G:

```
http://website.com/Cat-8/ID-1/Ads-4-3?page=1
```

redirect to

```
http://website.com/Cat-8/ID-1/Ads-4-3
```

Another E.G:

```
http://website.com/node/Item21?page=1
```

for example **i dont** want this pages redirect

```
http://website.com/node/Item21?page=1
```

With my code all url has been redirect !

there is :

> if ($arg_page != "") { return 301 $uri; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`rewrite`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) instead of `return`, as it can:

- target just those URLs that begin with `Cat-`, and
- it can easily remove the original query string

For example:

```
if ($arg_page != "") { rewrite ^(/Cat-.*)$ $1? permanent; }
```

**Important:** The `if` block [behaves differently](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) when placed inside a `location` block. So this code snippet is designed to be placed inside the `server` block.

Comment: which better **return** or **rewrite** ?

Comment: If you use return, you will need to find a way to target both conditions. At least, rewrite takes care of one condition, which means you can use an `if` to take care of the other. Depending on your configuration, you could use a `location /cat-` block to take care of one condition, but I would need to see the entire `server` block to know how to make it work.

Comment: Thank you richard !